# LG optimus black android mobile front camera issue

Tags: android

i am using LG optimus black android mobile.I tried to use front camera  using parameters.set("camera-id",2); but unable to access front camera it  always uses back camera. 
I am using android version 2.2.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

use [`Camera.open()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) and check [`CAMERA_FACING_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) to find the correct `Camera` to use.

On a side note, use the static variables, don't hard code them as ints.

Answer (score 0):

try `parameters.set("camera-sensor",2);`